# SQL query - strange behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
DECLARE @OrdersTemp TABLE
(
   OrderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO @OrdersTemp
  SELECT ord.Id
  FROM Orders 

--all rows count
SELECT  
    @RowsCount = COUNT(DISTINCT ord.Id)
FROM   Orders 


--@RowsCount = 5. It's right!

--second table with paging
DECLARE @OrdersTempWithPaging TABLE
(
    OrderId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO @OrdersTempWithPaging
   SELECT OrderId
   FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT OrderId,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) AS RowNum
          FROM @OrdersTemp) AS alias
          WHERE 
              RowNum BETWEEN (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1
                     AND @PageIndex * @PageSize

SELECT * FROM @OrdersTempWithPaging
--10 or more rows. It's wrong.
```

Why does `@OrdersTempWithPaging` return wrong amount of rows? How do I avoid it?

**UPDATE**:
The statement below returns 25 = 5*5 rows (instead of 5)

```
   INSERT  INTO @OrdersTempWithPaging
                SELECT    OrderId
                FROM    (
                          SELECT    OrderId,
                                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId ) AS RowNum
                          FROM      @OrdersTemp ) AS alias
                --WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
                             --  AND     @PageIndex * @PageSize
  SELECT * FROM @OrdersTempWithPaging
```

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @OrdersTemp` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (reversing the `DISTINCT` use):

```
INSERT INTO @OrdersTempWithPaging
   SELECT DISTINCT OrderId
   FROM  (SELECT OrderId,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) AS RowNum
          FROM @OrdersTemp) AS alias
   WHERE 
       RowNum BETWEEN (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1
              AND @PageIndex * @PageSize
```

If you need only distinct order-ids, you could have:

```
INSERT INTO @OrdersTemp
  SELECT DISTINCT ord.Id
  FROM Orders
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO @OrdersTempWithPaging
   SELECT OrderId
   FROM  (SELECT OrderId,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) AS RowNum
          FROM @OrdersTemp) AS alias
   WHERE 
       RowNum BETWEEN (@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1
              AND @PageIndex * @PageSize
```

Comment: 1 --- Doesn't work properly too. It returns 2 rows instead of 5. 2 --- Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Comment: Since there is a `WHERE` condition, I suppose it's normal to return fewer rows (2) than the original (5). What exactly do you want to achieve and what should it be returned?

Comment: I want to get result with paging from  @OrdersTempWithPaging .

Comment: @Alex: Why do you have `INSERT INTO @OrdersTemp SELECT ord.Id FROM Orders` in the first place and not `INSERT INTO @OrdersTemp SELECT DISTINCT ord.Id FROM Orders` ?

Answer (score 3):

It's because your ordering inside the select,

```
 SELECT    DISTINCT OrderId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId ) AS RowNumber
```

You have to coose an ordering over a column where you don't have to use DISTINCT in the selection.

```
 SELECT    OrderId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId ) AS RowNumber
```

Try it, without DISTINCT

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) AS RowNum
FROM @OrdersTemp
```

use

```
SELECT OrderId,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId) AS RowNum
FROM @OrdersTemp
GROUP BY OrderId
```

This is an interesting case of [another](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/29/sql-server-difference-between-distinct-and-group-by-distinct-vs-group-by/) [difference](https://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/03/24/group-by-v-distinct-group-by-wins.aspx) between `SELECT DISTINCT` and `SELECT GROUP BY`, which manifests itself when the select list includes a ranking function.

In the first query the output includes duplicate `OrderId` values from `@OrdersTemp` because the ranking function is evaluated *before* `DISTINCT` is applied . In contrast, the second query first groups the rows by `OrderId` (i.e. effectively selects distinct `OrderId` values first) and then applies ranking.